# Complexity of Max Bisection on cubic planar graphs?

Tags: computational-complexity

Max Bisection problem is to partition the set of nodes into two equal size sets such that the number of crossing edges is maximized. Max Bisection is $NP$-complete on cubic graphs and also on planar graphs.

> What is the complexity of Max Bisection on cubic planar graphs? Is it $NP$-complete?

Cross posted on [SE tcs](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/4323/complexity-of-max-bisection-on-cubic-planar-graphs)

Answer (score 1):

I am pretty sure that the result in 
http://rutcor.rutgers.edu/pub/rrr/reports2006/23_2006.pdf
tells us that Max-Bisection is NP-hard on bounded degree planar graphs (however, I think the bound is bigger than three) -- you would have to chase down their construction to be sure.

Answer (score 1):

Max-Cut, at least, in cubic graphs is NP-hard even to approximate to some factor .997.  This is due to Berman and Karpinski, 1999:

On some tighter inapproximability results. In Proceedings of the 26th International Colloquium on Automata, Languages and Programming, Prague, Czech Republic, pages 200–209, 1999.

I wouldn't doubt it if the optimal cut is a bisection in the "yes" case of the reduction.